# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token - al almacenar el valor de un camp de texto en una variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema al traer la informacion de un campo de texto de 350 caracteres y que fue ingresado en un campo de tipo text y que en la descripcion de este campo se utilizo la tecla enter, para escribir en otra linea.

Visualizo el siguiente error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Pregunta como puedo solucionar que una variable acepte un campo que fue ingresado presionando la tecla enter

[image: Imagen del error]

Comment: La imagen de código no ayuda, pega el código mejor. De paso, algo como esto `a = "hola""` tiraría el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Este es el codigo: el valor del campo txt_observa =

```js
function inicializarDatos() {
    
if (!esnulo($('#hid_reg_compras').val())) {

 $('#sel_tip_comprobante').val(cod_comprobante);     
 $('#txt_fec_comprobante').val('${compra.fec_comprobante}');
 $('#txt_ser_comprobante').val('${compra.ser_comprobante}');
 $('#txt_observa').val("${compra.des_glosa}");  //**Este es el campo de texto**
 $('#sel_for_pago').val('${compra.cod_med_pago}');
```

El error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

que se refiere al campo txt_observa que tiene problemas al visualizar su informacion; ya que fue registrado en dos lineas presionando enter; tal como se muestra en la imagen...
Como puedo resolverlo

El error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]